# How to programmatically read until a certain character in a file?

Tags: linux, file, c, io, json

My `C` program writes a `.json` file. Few of the values in the schema of the .json file is string and has variable length.

I am using [`jansson`](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) library. I will have to read a complete .json `object` otherwise the library raises an error. So, I cannot read anything less than a complete object or more than the complete object. I am using `File I/O` in C and reading characters to a `char` array.

So, if I statically allocate size of the array, but each object varies in number of characters present.

Is there a way to dynamically assign the number of characters to the `char` array, so that I can read till the end of a particular object?

**OR**

Is there a way to read in the entire contents of a file without knowing the number of characters in the file?

**OR**

Should I use a `struct` to write the .json file? But this will present a problem with braces, commas and colons which will make the `struct` difficult to maintain.

Comment: Why "read in the entire contents of a file" if you do *not* want to read the entire object anyway? Is your json object complicated, or is it more like a simple list?

Comment: It is fairly simple, @Jongware. Since I am using an array and there will be lot of items in the array, and both opening and closing braces should be present when reading the part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is there a way to read in the entire contents of a file without knowing the number of characters in the file?*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long GetFileSize(FILE *fp){
    long fsize = 0;

    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fp); 
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);//reset stream position!!

    return fsize;
}

char *ReadToEnd(const char *filepath){
    FILE *fp;
    long fsize;
    char *buff;

    if(NULL==(fp=fopen(filepath, "rb"))){
        perror("file cannot open at ReadToEnd\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    fsize=GetFileSize(fp);
    buff=malloc(fsize+1);
    fread(buff, sizeof(char), fsize, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    buff[fsize]='\0';

    return buff;
}
```

---

read an object from a file with jansson :

```
json_t *obj;
json_error_t error;

obj = json_load_file("data.json", 0, &error);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file descriptor from which you are reading the json object, you can use `getline` to dynamically allocate the needed memory for you by setting `*lineptr=NULL` in your `getline` call (**see: man getline**). This will read an entire line (up to the newline) of input from your FILE. e.g.:

```
char *lineptr = NULL;
size_t n = 0;
ssize_t len = 0;
FILE *jsonfd;

jsonfd = fopen (filename, mode);
if (jsonfd == NULL)
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

len = getline (&lineptr, &n, jsonfd);
printf ("read '%zd' characters: %s\n", len, lineptr);
```

If you have more than 1 line on the input, you can place your `getline` call in a while loop:

```
while ((len = getline (&lineptr, &n, jsonfd)) != -1)
{
    process as needed
}
```

You should be able to parse and write your json string to the file without needing to use a struct to handle the data. Once you have read the information into your character array (`lineptr` above) you will have the flexibility to write what you need.